# Why Network Manager is not available to new user accounts in 16.04? Why nm-applet does not start for new users?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, autostart, user-management

Network Manager (nm-applet) is not available in the panel for new user accounts, and manually running nm-applet does not start the network manager.

I needed to create 2 accounts for different users, and gave them administrator level and also permission to create and connect to networks.
But nm-applet does not autostart and do not launches running from the terminal. It simply won't say anything after running nm-applet. There's no simple way to make it run.

I followed the workarounds for previous releases, such:

- making sure that "indicator plugin" is active on the panel,
- and, in Application Autostart tab of "session and startup"

  - "network" is configured to autostart,
  - "Indicator Application" are configured to not autostart,
  - added nm-applet command for it to autostart.

As a system administrator I can't figure out what else should a user do to access networking.

Network Manager is running for the default (1000) user. (BTW default user is connecting to WI-FI without specific permission to do it.)
The new users accounts were given users ID below 1000 for they to not appear on login window.

NOTE: We are running "ubuntu desktop" sessions, after installing "ubuntu studio" packages, on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. New users are being created on "users and gropus" option in the System category of the Whisker menu.

Comment: UPDATE: nm-applet began to start normally after two system reboots. (User logout and re-login did not fix it.)
This issue didn't affect user accounts created with User IDs equal or major than 1000.
So, THIS BUG ONLY AFFECTS: new user accounts with User IDs below 1000, and just after system is rebooted twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of your network device, try **ipconfig *device* up**
If you don't know the name of the device, try ifconfig and iwconfig and look for the device name. If you don't see the device name, or you don't know where to find it, update your original post with the output of the commands.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This issue got solved after two reboots.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion iwconfig allowed me to configure my Network Monitor plugin in my panel.

Comment: if this helped you, please mark my post as solved